# How to create a test suite to run specific test cases using Junit4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm very new to `AndroidStudio`. We are writing our `Automation` test cases using `Espresso` and `Junit4`. We have around 50 automated test cases. Our concern is we want to select some 25 automated test case and run it every time. How to create a suite of 25 automated test case and run it? Can someone help us here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to run specific test suit/test.

You can split the specific tests you want into a separate package and use the gradle's connectedAndroidTest task to run on that package:

> ./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=Your test class path

Comment: Can you please provide some kind of example how to implement this?